# Vertx Kafka client consumer example not working and no errors are displayed

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, vert.x

Does anyone manage to put this example working?
http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-kafka-client/java/

I tried to connect to a running Kafka and Vertx-kafka-client 3.5.0, without success.
What's more strange, running this small code snippet, but without any kafka cluster at all, the consumer says it subscribes successfully.

```
public class KafkaConsumerExampleVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        KafkaConsumerExampleVerticle verticle = new KafkaConsumerExampleVerticle();
        Vertx.vertx().deployVerticle(verticle);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {

        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = createKafkaConsumer();

        consumer.handler(m -> {
            System.out.println("Consumer | message received: " + m);
        });

        consumer.subscribe("topic1", h -> {
            if (h.succeeded()) {
                System.out.println("Consumer subscribed!");
            } else if (h.failed()){
                System.out.println("Consumer failed: " + h.cause());                
            }
        });

    }

    private KafkaConsumer<String, String> createKafkaConsumer() {
        Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.68.99.100:9092");
        config.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        config.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        config.put("group.id", "my_group");
        config.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
        config.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = KafkaConsumer.create(vertx, config);
        return consumer;
    }

}
```

It doesn't matter which IP I put there or if I have any kafka cluster running or not, the Consumer subscribes successfully.
Is this the intended behavior? How one know what's wrong with the settings if it will succeeds?

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you are seeing is what we expect due to how the underlying used "native" Kafka client behaves.
The consumer.subscribe method calls the underlying "subscribe" method offered by the "native" client which doesn't start any connection so any communication with the broker (it just saves information about subscription locally).
The "native" Kafka client starts all the connection with the broker (so sending the subscribing request in this case) only when the native "poll" method is called.
At this point another issue comes : actually the "native" poll method hangs if the specified broker isn't reachable. Really it doesn't hang but it starts to send a "find coordinator" request waiting for a response. The default "request.timeout.ms" is 305000 (about 5 minutes) until it considers the request failed. Even if you set this value to a lower value, the request fails but the connection failure is detected later.

Comment: Considering your answer, I rerun my test and waited for 5 minutes after subscribing the Consumer, and no error or feedback is given in the console. Is there any way to detect wrong settings in an effective way? I also don't understand what's wrong with my configuration since I do have a running Kafka at 192.68.99.100:9092.

Comment: you could add log4j to your project and the a log4j.properties file with the configuration having the INFO level in order to have info from the native consumer library.

Comment: I have just tested on my PC where I'm running the Kafka broker, a console producer and your application. I can receive the messages published by the producer. I can see your log message "Consumer | message received: " alongside with the something like this "io.vertx.kafka.client.consumer.impl.KafkaConsumerRecordImpl@603d472c" because there is no implementation for toString() which is something I'm going to add but in any case the messages are received. Can you give me a little bit more information about which Vert.x and Kafka broker versions are you using ?